Clicking on the right side of the text
Is it possible to detect clicks on the full width of the QListWidget's item?
In the screencast (preview in Designer), you see that the selection only changes when I click on the text:

When I click on the white space right of the text, the selection does not change.
Edit: As Daniel wrote below in the comments, this also happens in Scribus. The relevant files seem to be:

https://github.com/scribusproject/scribus/blob/master/scribus/ui/preferencesdialogbase.ui
https://github.com/scribusproject/scribus/blob/master/scribus/ui/preferencesdialog.cpp#L246


I've never seen this behavior, and clicking should work on the whole area. Did you test on a real program? What Qt and OS version? Are you sure you're not adding some overlayed widget? Consider providing the ui file.

This behavior occurs in scribus menus (e.g. preferences) - I can't quite find the relevant file, perhaps it's this one: https://github.com/scribusproject/scribus/blob/master/scribus/ui/preferencesdialogbase.ui. Also here preview of a preferences menu in scribus: https://ibb.co/3v65zHH

@a.l.e That is an empty UI with unrelated widgets, and the cpp file is irrelevant without other context. Please address what asked before.

@musicamante: the UI file was probably very relevant (at least, I think that I've found in there the difference with a clean QListWidget, see my self answer below) and the referenced function in the .cpp file is setting further options for the List (it might have been relevant)... Or am I missing something? The UI file has been created with an unkonwn version of Qt, people are compiling with somehow current versions of Qt 6 on different OSes (at least Mint, Debian and Windows) and see the wrong behavior.

@a.l.e What I meant is that there were other elements in the UI and implementation, and we cannot know if your UI/code has the same problem: the fact that they have the same result could be just by coincidence. The code may have been relevant, but the scope of SO is to provide self contained answers and questions: checking a long code in a repo (which will probably change in the future) of a third party project is not something we normally accept. That's why it is almost always important to provide a proper [mre] in the question.

Yes, you're right: providing a reproducible example is mostly very useful. Sadly, until I've read your assertion that you have never seen that behavior (and contradict the maintainer who was asserting that this is the typical Qt behavior) I could not come up with such an example. After that, trying to create a reproducible example brought me to a possible solution (which another maintainer has now committed: if nobody complains about the new settings, we can call it a day).

@a.l.e I can confirm that that is not the default behavior, and the discriminant is the usage of itemAlignment(): when left (or set) to the default 0, clicking works in any part of the item bounding rect. In fact, that feature seems bugged: if you set the alignment to the right, the text is left aligned, and it doesn't fill the whole width, clicking doesn't even work anymore in the expected region of the text, but in the supposed region if it was aligned on the right. I'd suggest you to update your post with a proper UI (or specifying the above property requirement), and also update »

@a.l.e » the answer accordingly. Right now it's not very clear what the Scribus reference would be important in the question, since it's primarily a Qt issue, and the further reference in the answer isn't really meaningful to the purpose of the answer itself (anybody that is not using Scribus would be puzzled by its inclusion). A simple possible solution (other than not setting the alignment) would be to use a subclass and override indexAt(), then if the default call doesn't result in a valid index, you could iterate all items and check if the event pos is within the visualRect().

I edited the self answer and tried to make it clear why Scribus is referenced.

I was under the wrong assumption, that what I was seeing was the standard Qt behavior.
musicamante's comment made it clear that it is not the case.
(I was seeing the behavior with an existing .ui file from the Scribus project).
I've then created a new QListWidget in a new Dialog: and there it works as they say.
I then compared the options for the two QListWidgets (the one from Scribus and the one newly created) and the result is: among other differences, in the existing list, Scribus has enabled AlignLeft and AlignLeading in the itemAlignment section. Turning them off, makes the list makes the items to be clickable on the full length (at least, then, the full line can be selected in the Designer's preview).
In the specific case, this might not be possible because of the content of the list: icon + label + wrapping of the text.
I will let the developer who is maintaining this dialog check, if it's ok to disable them.
Thank you for your hints!
(Edited to make it more clear why Scribus is mentioned in the answer)

This is probably caused by the way QListView selects items and how the style eventually returns a "selectable area" for the item. See the overridden implementation of indexAt() of QListView, which calls the internal intersectingSet(). The function is relatively complex, as it has to consider the possibility of overlapping items (eg. when using the IconMode or with the Free` movement), and the style may only consider a portion of the whole item for collision detection. Some styles use the whole area, including the icon, others only the bounding rect of the text.

Thank you for the further information! A maintainer has now committed the changes I have proposed above. If any unwanted behavior (misalignment...) appear in some setups, we will have to dig further into this. For now, I will assume that those settings were left over of very old code and not needed anymore (as an example, the UI defines an horizontal list and the .cpp code redefines it as a vertical one...). Again, thanks for your hints.
